# Laravel RAW query is orders of magnitude slower than the same query outside of Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and PHP 7.0.6 on Debian. MySQL is 5.5.30 on a remote server.

When I run the query through HeidiSQL or from the command line client it executes in about 0.2 seconds. Executing the exact same SQL in Laravel (debug mode on or off) takes nearly 500 seconds. I tried pulling the Laravel query out of the MySQL query log and running it, and it ran fast. It's only when executing the statement through Laravel that it's slow. The laravel code is below. My timer code is before and after this line, so the slowdown is definitely here. The query only returns one row.

```
$results = \DB::select($sql);
```

An anonymized version of the query is below (business-specific data would otherwise be visible). Hopefully I haven't mangled anything in the process.

```
SELECT  ll.id,
    ll.other_id,
    ll.third_id,
    ll.created_at,
    ll.h_id,
    ll.sub,
    ll.sub2,
    ll.status,
    px.created_at,
    b.abbr,
    ldl.transaction_id,
    ldl.purchase_price,
    CONCAT(ld.first_name, ' ', ld.last_name) as fullname,
    lcase(ll.email_address) as email_address,
    ll.total_revenue

FROM    table1 ll
INNER JOIN table2 ld on ll.id = ld.fid
INNER JOIN table3 ldl on ll.id = ldl.fid
LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 px on ll.id = px.fid
INNER JOIN table5 b on ldl.bid = b.id

WHERE ll.created_at > '2016-05-04 00:00:00'
AND ll.created_at < '2016-05-04 23:59:59'
AND v_id IN (41,42,43,45,46)
AND ldl.b_id IN (131)
AND lcase(ll.email_address) in ('example@email.com')
AND ll.status = 'ACCEPTED'
```

Comment: Show us your $sql variable.

Comment: Nothing about this query looks speedy at all. What's your indexing like on that table? Can you use `BETWEEN` for `created_at` comparisons? What does `EXPLAIN` have to say? It's possible that you're hitting some kind of resource lock inside Laravel. Strip this query down to the absolute minimum to eliminate factors in your diagnosis. Like `SELECT ll.id FROM table1 ll LIMIT 1` as a start.

Comment: @tadman what sort of resource locks inside of Laravel? Whilst the query can be optimised, the question thus far appears to be why might Laravel (or in turn PHP) perform this query in a less optimised way than the other described means. The observed difference seems to be when executed using Laravel's DBAL (Fluent) and any other involvoled components. I'd be interested in your thoughts on what in the framework might cause difference between 0.2s and 500s when executing the query.

Comment: If it is exactly the same query being run, which I suspect is not the case, on exactly the same database, and the only variable here is direct query vs. inside Laravel then there must be some other factor involved. A transaction or a query that fails to run to completion and times out after 500s which holds up this query is the most likely candidate. You need to *simplify* here and come up with the most minimal example of something that takes forever to run. If that's `SELECT 1` you're going to have to keep digging.

Comment: @Dave did you ever resolve this? I'm experiencing the same exact problem.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this issue and finally found a solution. I had a query that when I ran on the command line it executed in about 40ms. When I put the same exact query into Laravel using:

```
DB::select( $myQuery ); // Where $myQuery is the exact string I ran on the command line
```

...the query took about 1 minute. Something was clearly wrong.

In the end, it had everything to do with **parameter binding**. By simply changing this:

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='Andrew'");
```

...to this:

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :name",['name' => 'Andrew']);
```

My problem was solved.

Comment: IIRC, a parameterized query's execution plan can be cached and re-used, so the above approach would indeed offer potential benefits if this query is frequently ran with different `name`  values.

Comment: I have the same problem but this solution doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

For any else struggling with this, we experienced a similar issue when querying a db **view**, but the solution was the opposite of the above.

When running this query in the DB directly, the response time was a fraction of a second.:

```
select * from `db_view` where `id` = 12345;
```

But when using fluent builder for the same query, response was > 12 seconds (!):

```
DB::table('db_view')->where('id', $this->id)->first();
```

Seems from mysql `show full processlist` that the db was creating a sort index every time the query was called, but only when called from Laravel, for some reason.

We tried this, as per the answer above, but it didn't help either:

```
DB::select("select * from `db_view` where `id` = :id", ['id' => $this->id])[0];
```

In the end, we tried excluding the binding entirely and it finally worked as expected, without building a sort index for each query:

```
DB::select("select * from `db_view` where `id` = {$this->id}")[0];
```